# Check if name is defined?

Tags: python

I want to check is name "my_name" (which is my class object) defined already. How can I do it w/out using try-except:

```
try:
    if c:
        print("ok")
except NameError:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if 'c' in locals():
    print ('Ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

If you need to check for global use globals() instead

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `try`/`except`, you could lookup the `locals()` and `globals()`. Such a check would look like:

```
if locals().get('c', globals().get('c')) is None:
    print "no"
else:
    print "ok"
```

The call in the `if` condition would lookup the local variables first, and if your variable isn't found there, would then lookup global variables. If the variable isn't found in one or the other, `None` is returned

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if c is set to None.

Comment: @awatts indeed, good point. If you know in advance what types are expected to be found then adding a call to `isinstance()` could help, but I believe the selected answer is best for most cases (and more readable).